# Discuss the trigger for database table changes

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, triggers, sql-grant

hy,
This trigger will give me whole table record with all changes butt i want to get the last changed row share the code.

```
Create Or Replace Trigger TRG_check IN
Before insert or update
on temp_checkin
FOR each ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO temp_checkin_history
select * from temp_checkin
where temp_checkin.id = temp_checkin.id;
END;
```

thanks

Comment: Check your spellings my friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a query like `INSERT INTO SELECT *` without specifying the columns is a bad practice. Also, there is no need to select from the trigger owner table like you are doing. Instead, use `:NEW` keyword and specify all columns. You may write your trigger as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_check BEFORE
    INSERT OR UPDATE ON temp_checkin
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO temp_checkin_history (
        id,
        col1,
        col2,
        col3
    ) --other columns
     VALUES (
        :new.id,
        :new.col1,
        :new.col2,
        :new.col3
    ); -- other columns prefixed by :NEW

END;
```

Comment: I need immediate Trigger for DDL activity.(When a command is fired its log is  generated